# React-Native Image sizing in View with unknown size

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

React-Naive suggests developers to state image dimension before runtime. I know this is a good practice. My question is... How about if I want to resize an `<Image>` to the same width as its contained `<View>` with unknown width?

For example, I have an `<Image>` in a `<View>` with `rowDirection: 'row', flex: 0.8`. In different device I have different screen width. How do I know the actual width of 80% of the device?

P.S. I have tried all `resizeMode` but no luck.

Can anyone help me thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried this snippet

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#CCF' }}>
    <Image
        source={require('../resources/images/side-menu-header.png')}
        style={{ width: null, height: null, flex: 0.8 }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 0.2 }} />
</View>
```

[Result image of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsO5Y.jpg)

However, yes, this image is now set to 0.8 in width, but some its area has been cropped. This is not what I want to get. Therefore, I set its `resizeMode` to `contain` as below snippet

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#CCF' }}>
    <Image
        resizeMode='contain'
        source={require('../resources/images/side-menu-header.png')}
        style={{ width: null, height: null, flex: 0.8 }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 0.2 }} />
</View>
```

[Result image of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrIL4.jpg)

This is not what I expected too! As you see, the image is now become 0.8 in width and the whole image is shown, but the top and bottom space is occupied by its original dimension. (The Original image dimension is large)

I think I can simplify this question in few words: How do I show a full width image in my app? I cannot set its width to 1080 since not all device has a width of 1080 pixel.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to stretch the image? If so, changed `resizeMode` to `'stretch'`. If do not want to stretch, but want the image to "cover" the background while maintaining aspect ratio, then change `resizeMode` to `'cover'`.

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi I want to show the whole image without lossing its aspect ratio.

Comment: Then you need to use the `resizeMode='contain'`. If your screen / container does not fit the aspect ratio of your image, then there is nothing else you can do without adding padding.

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you want to happen?

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi [This](http://imgur.com/SidPIiB) is what I want...

Comment: The problem is in the parent(s) of the `<View>` element. Can you paste the container of the `<View>`?

Comment: It is just a full page `<View>` element.
like this: `<View style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: {5} }}>...</View>`

Comment: Sure there are no `alignItems: 'center'` styles being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dimensions API for making image size dynamic.

Sample code:

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
<Image
    source={{uri: `${url}`}}
    style={{ width: width * 0.8, height: height * 0.8 }}
/>
```

The **width * 0.8 and height * 0.8** is the 80 percentage for your screen size width and height respectively.

Comment: So... that means if my image is nested in multiple `<View>` level hierarchy with size in percentage, then I should take all of them to calculate with the screen size?

Comment: Yes... Better to calculate the image with screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `width` and `height` of `null` to the `style` prop, like so:

```
<Image resizeMode='cover' source={{ uri: 'image.png' }} style={{ width: null, height: null, flex: 0.8 }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm concerned, what you need is a api to get the size of device.

Try Dimensions, use like this:

```js
let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```